# Undoing a specific action in Vim

Tags: vim

Is there a way to save a specific action so I can undo just that action at a later time, and not have to undo everything else I did in the meantime? Specifically, I'm looking for a way to insert newlines with textwidth, but remove them later.

Answer (score 2):

See http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html#undo-blocks :

> To do the opposite (to `:undojoin` — *phd*), break a change into two undo blocks, **in Insert mode use <kbd>CTRL-G</kbd> <kbd>u</kbd>** (emphasize mine — *phd*).  This is useful if you want an insert command to be undoable in parts.

http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-G_u

> Setting the value of 'undolevels' also breaks undo.  Even when the new value is equal to the old value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write paired functions, say, `InsertLines()` and `RemoveLines()`. Then you can call them to `undo` each other for your needs.

---

Vim undo history has to track text states strictly and sequently, because they are interdependent. Most programs usually allow a user to cancel the last one or more commands executed. It's hard to undo something in the middle but ignore that it may have already totally changed.